# Simplest experiment to see quantum interference of $|HH \rangle + |VV \rangle $?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, interference

What is the simplest experiment that I can perform to see interference of $|HH \rangle + |VV \rangle $, assuming this is an entangled state of two photons in two different polarizations?

Ideally I want an operation that causes the probabilities of measuring HH or VV to oscillate.

Comment: What do you mean by "see interference"? What are the two things that are interfering?  What do you mean by "experiment"? (Your answer doesn't talk about an experiment *at all*, as far as I can tell.) What does "the result of HH and VV" mean (from your answer)? When you say "oscillate", do you mean oscillate as a function of time? Or oscillate back and forth after every application of some quantum gate? Etc. It's difficult to understand what you're asking (or what your answer mean).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "seeing interference", but if you mean seeing evidence of entanglement then:  1) Take many pairs of photons in the same entangled state.  2)  Observe the polarizations of different photons in different directions. 3) Verify that your results are consistent (at whatever significance level you choose) with the predictions of quantum mechanics.

Comment: I have already made it very clear what I want. I want to see quantum interference of the HH and VV state such that the probability amplitudes interfere, similar the behavior of a qMZI. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: I am not simply asking how to verify the bell inequalities...

Answer (score -1):

The entangled state you mention is the phi+ state, one of 4 Bell States.  You need special setups to obtain any kind of interference effects with entangled states, as the more common double slit interference experiments will not produce visible interference effects.  However, there are setups that demonstrate interference of entangled photon pairs.

1. So called Quantum Eraser and DCQE (delayed choice quantum eraser) experiments demonstrate interference effects that can only be seen via coincidence detection (i.e. detection of both photons by different detectors).  Here is a classic version of that:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106078

"We report a quantum eraser experiment which actually uses a Young double-slit to create interference."

2. Another important type of interference in entangled systems is called the Hong-Ou-Mandel dip interference.  See page 13 of the *very* comprehensive review of interference and entanglement (71 pages!) by a top team:

[Multi-photon entanglement and interferometry (2011)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.2853.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

The entanglement mediating the interaction between HH -> (HH+VV) can be represented as a unitary operator of the form:

[[1, 1],[1, -1]].[HH, VV]

If we take the output of an entangled state and re-apply the operation again, then we get interference on the result of HH and VV.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say but entanglement is not an operator, unitary or otherwise.